# How to access fileprivate properties from another class?

Tags: swift, properties, scope

It is my understanding that fileprivate properties can be accessed from another class in the same .swift file.

How can I format this code to get rid of the "Use of unresolved identifier 'fileprivateProperty' " error?

```
import Foundation

class FirstClass {

    fileprivate var fileprivateProperty = "This is a fileprivate property"

}

class SecondClass {

    init() {

        func printProperty() {
            print("\(fileprivateProperty)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the “fileprivate” attribute. `fileprivateProperty` is still a property of `FirstClass` and not of `SecondClass`.

Comment: Objects of `FirstClass` and `SecondClass` aren't related. You could imagine these two objects being `Human` and `Car`. What you're doing is the equivalent of a `Car` object trying to access `familyName`. Of which human? Well, it isn't clear. It doesn't make sense to ask for a `fileprivateProperty`, without asking for the `fileprivateProperty` of a specific object of `FirstClass`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right the fileprivate properties can be access within a swift file. but you still need to create object or reference for first class before access its properties.

```
import Foundation

class FirstClass {

fileprivate var fileprivateProperty = "This is a fileprivate property"

}

class SecondClass {

init() {

    func printProperty() {
        print("\(FirstClass().fileprivateProperty)")
    }
 }
}
```

like this.